# Is it possible to add effects to the MediaElementAudioSourceNode without distorting the sound, using the Web Auido API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api

I am attempting to manipulate the volume by connecting a [MediaElementAudioSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaElementAudioSourceNode) and a [GainNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode).
Below is a demo of it.
[CodeSandBoxs](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-worker-sgyrm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

If you press the Play button, the music plays normally.
However, manipulating `input type=range` to change the volume distorts the sound you are playing.(Turn the volume down if you try.)

Is there a way to change the volume without distorting the sound?
Or is this an unavoidable thing if you use MediaElementAudioSourceNode?
I looked for an article that mentions the phenomenon of sound distortion, but I could not find it.

In the demo we only aim to change the volume, but we also want to add reverb, delay, etc.

---

The demo code is as follows.

```js
let audio, gainNode;

const App = () => {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    audio = new Audio("/piano.mp3");
    audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
    const sourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
    sourceNode.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    return () => audioCtx.close();
  }, []);

  const playPause = () => {
    if (playing) {
      audio.pause();
      setPlaying(false);
      return;
    }
    audio.play();
    setPlaying(true);
  };

  const cahngeVolume = (e) => (gainNode.gain.value = e.target.value);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={playPause} style={{ display: "block" }}>
        {playing ? "Pause" : "Play"}
      </button>
      <div>
        <span>Volume</span>
        <input type="range" onChange={cahngeVolume} step="any" />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the distortion is probably that the range of the `GainNode` doesn't really map to the range of your input. By default the min/max values of a range input are 0 and 100. However the `GainNode` does multiply the signal by its gain value. That means the slider should ideally have a max value of 1.

```
<input type="range" onChange={cahngeVolume} step="any" max="1" />
```

That way the slider goes from 0 (no sound) to 1 (no amplification).